# Configure SQL connection pool in Spring Boot web app deployed in Azure App Service

Tags: azure, spring-boot, connection-pooling, spring-java-config

I implemented a REST API in Spring Boot and deployed it in an Azure App Service (Java 8, Tomcat 8.5) instance. This application connects to an Azure SQL instance.

*Note: This is not an embedded web server but the PaaS based Azure App Service Tomcat platform*

I am trying to figure out how to set up a database connection pool in the bootstrapping main class of the Spring Boot application using Java Config, so it can be auto-wired into the `@Repository` annotated classes so corresponding `JdbcTemplate` instances can be set up with the `DataSource` instances facilitated by the connection pool.

Currently, I am setting up the database properties in Spring Boot's `application.properties` which *automagically* sets up the `DataSource`:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://<azure-sql-connection-string>
spring.datasource.username=dbadmin
spring.datasource.password=dbpassword
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

This allows me to auto-wire a `JdbcTemplate` in the `@Repository` annotated DAO implementation class:

```
@Autowired
private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
```

which then allows me to interact with the database using `JdbcTemplate`. There is no JPA/ORM involved... standard SQL at this point, due to the dynamic nature of the SQL queries used by the application.

How do I set up a connection pool? I know this will significantly improve database performance.

Answer (score 0):

I added the following method-level annotation `@Bean` in the `@SpringBootApplication` (bootstrap) main class:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource(Map<String,String> dbProps) {

    DataSourceBuilder factory = DataSourceBuilder.create()
            .driverClassName(dbProps.get("SQLDriverClassName"))
            .type(BasicDataSource.class)
            .url(dbProps.get("SQLDatabaseUrl"))
            .username(dbProps.get("SQLDatabaseUsername"))
            .password(dbProps.get("SQLDatabasePassword"));

    return factory.build();
}
```

The following dependencies were required in my Spring Boot application's POM:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.0.jre8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

This appears to be working. Not sure if this is the recommended way to configure though.